# How to use alarm perl function to set a timeout on a Python command running on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

In a Perl script, I would like to run a Python command and kill it if it is not over after 5 seconds. Here is the code I use:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use autodie qw(open);

my $fcmd;
my $status;
my $child_pid;

eval {
    # If we receive a ALRM signal, we kill the child process (which will be Python)
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { kill( 9, $child_pid ); die("alarm\n"); };
    # Set the timeout to 5 seconds
    alarm(5);
    
    # Run infinite loop in Python
    $child_pid = open( $fcmd, "python -c \"while True: 1+1\" 2>&1 |" );
    
    # Looping on $fcmd also acts as waitpid
    # This is blocking while the child process does not end
    while ( my $line = <$fcmd> ) {
        print("PRINT: $line\n");
    }
    
    close $fcmd;
    alarm(0); 
    $status = $?;
};

if ($@) {
    print("timeout\n");
}
```

In this script, I set the alarm to 5 seconds and I run an infinite loop inside a Python process using `open` (I add some redirect and a pipe to be able to read the output).
However, the script never ends and I have nothing in the output.

Why the command is not stopped by the alarm signal?

NOTE: I cannot use any other Perl modules.

---

After reading @Bork comment, I changed the Python command to print something:

```perl
$child_pid = open( $fcmd, "python -c \"while True: print('Hello')\" 2>&1 |" );
```

And this worked! I correctly have "Hello" in the output and it stopped after 5 seconds.
It seems that the behavior is different if the command executed in `open` output data or not. How could I fix that to have the same behavior in both cases?

Comment: Are you saying your print statement never prints? I don't know Python, but I assume that loop gives no output, so Perl cannot read output from the process

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. Perl very poorly emulates `alarm`. It's no surprise it doesn't work.

Comment: I'd use IPC::Run, which allow you to provide a timeout.

Comment: @Bork I edit my question. Indeed, at first, the print statement was never displayed because the Python command does not print anything. I changed it in order to display "Hello". But now, the timeout works. I would like the timeout to work even if the Python command does not display anything.

Comment: @ikegami I cannot use any other modules.

Comment: Well that's dumb.

Comment: @Pierre How long are you waiting for the process to die? If you are causing an infinite loop it perhaps locks your system to the point where the alarm gets pushed way back. Most actual code has some process time, which may be why print works. Add some more code to the Python command. Also, the while loop in Perl waits for a readline end, so if a newline never comes, that will just sit and wait forever. You could find another way to listen to the process. Or if you are not interested in the output anyway, just add a sleep command that is higher than the alarm timeout.

Comment: @Pierre Also, there are ways to use modules, even if you do not have permission to install them on your system.

Comment: "_I cannot use any other modules_"  -- I don't mean to be rude but that's nonsense.  Sure you can "use modules."

Comment: @zdim What I meant is that I have restrictions on the 3P that I can use and importing a new module is not a simple operation.

Comment: @Bork Indeed, the issue comes from the fact that `<$fcmd>` is blocking and waits for the child process to send data in the pipe. If not, it hangs and the signal is never sent. It works if I do not look at the data sent by the child process (if I use waitpid, for instance) but I need the data on the fly.

Comment: "_I have restrictions on the 3P ... importing a new module is not a simple operation_"  -- I don't know what "3P" means, but you don't "_import_" anything.  Most libraries are "installed" by being just copied as single files, which you can put into your user space.  Then they sit there exactly like a module you may have written. Even if your code needs to run in very specific environments, you are allowed to organize it in modules, right?  Per standard programming practice.  Then why can't you dump ("install") a module from internet there as well?

Comment: @Pierre I don't understand. You want the data from the process, but you don't want it to display anything?

Comment: @zdim A 3P is a third-party. Some company restricts the usage of 3P for security reasons.

Comment: @Bork Maybe I was unclear, I need the data from the process to display it on the fly, even when the child process is not over.

Comment: @Pierre  "_A 3P is a third-party. Some company restricts the usage of 3P for security reasons._"  --  look, this is programming. You _cannot_ do realistic work without libraries from outside the core of the language at hand.  In Perl, you can't do database, particular file formats (XML, HTML, JSON...), gui, IPC, ... to name a few tasks I recall readily.  Just can't do them without "external" libraries.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> alarm   (Win32) Emulated using timers that must be explicitly polled
>         whenever Perl wants to dispatch "safe signals" and therefore
>         cannot interrupt blocking system calls.
> ```

— [perldoc perlport](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlport)

Windows doesn't have SIGALRM, and the way that Perl simulates it can't be relied on to interrupt a process that's blocking on I/O.

The most obvious workaround — to use non-blocking I/O and `select` to wait until you either receive some input or hit the timeout, doesn't seem like it will work either, as `select` is marked as "only implemented on sockets".

A brute-force workaround could be to fork another child process which sleeps and then attempts to kill the first child, but using either IPC::Run or an async framework would be preferable.